# Checking file system all the time when I reboot Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, check-disk

Recently, I have my Windows 7 checking file system all the time when I reboot/boot it. I already run the check many times, but the message keeps popping.

The message is

```
checking file system on C:
Th type of the file system is NTFS.

One of your disks needs to be checked for consistenncy. You
may cancel the disk check, but it is strongly recommended
that you continue.
```

And it'll take hours to finish the check. I can cancel the task, but I sometimes reboot the PC remotely, so it's very annoying.

Why do I have this message over and over again? How can I reboot normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition is what Windows refers to as *"setting the dirty bit"* and you have to unset that bit. If the dirty bit is set,then autochk performs an immediate chkdsk /f on that volume. This is usually caused by an unusual shutdown or a power loss during a read/write operation.

**This could possibly fix it:**

> Click ***Start*** and type ***cmd*** in the search programs and files dialog box. Then type  ***fsutil dirty query c:***.

This query  will return an answer if your drive is dirty or not. Most likely its dirty

> Next, type ***chkntfs /x c:***.

The ***x*** tells Windows to **not** check that particular drive on the next reboot. At this point reboot your computer, it should not perform a chkdsk on startup and take you directly to Windows.

When you are back in Windows you want to do a manual check disk on the c drive, to do this:

> Click ***Start*** and type ***cmd***
>   in the search programs and files
>   dialog box. Now type **chkdsk /f /r
>   c:**

This should take you through 5 stages of the scan and will unset that dirty bit.Since this will have to run a checkdisk on your C drive it will ask you to run it on your next restart.

> Finally, type **fsutil dirty query c:**

This will confirm that the dirty bit is not set on that drive. Hopefully this resolves your problem.